# Combining figures and a table using subcaption

Tags: tables, floats, subcaption

I am trying to combine three images and a table, such that i can use one caption for all of them. The goals is for them to be aligned such that they make a neat square.

the code I used is:

```
\documentclass{dissertation}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[english]{babel}     % Engelse text
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subcaption} 

\newcommand{\dtoprule}{\specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{0.4pt}%
\specialrule{0.3pt}{0pt}{\belowrulesep}%}
\newcommand{\dbottomrule}{\specialrule{0.3pt}{0pt}{0.4pt}%
\specialrule{1pt}{0pt}{\belowrulesep}%}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[htb]     
    \centering

    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{"Figures/Linear regression/LinearReg_Fib"}}

    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{"Figures/Linear regression/LinearReg_RBC"}}

    \subcaptionbox{}{\includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{"Figures/Linear regression/LinearReg_Leuko"}}

    \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{cccc}
                \dtoprule
                & C10    & C01     \\
                \midrule 
                F/P low           & 240.1  & 171.3  \\
                F/P   & 763.5  & 269.08  \\
                F/P mo & 1201.0 & 190.6   \\
                F/P h  & 6651.6 & -345.9 \\
                \dbottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{threeparttable}

    \caption{\textbf{Linear regression model between sample stiffness (determined as the tangent modulus at 75\%) and (a) Fibrin/platelet content, (b) Red blood cells and (c) Leukocytes}}
    \label{fig:LinearRegression}
\end{figure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the included image you can see the result. Basically, what I want is for the table to move up a little, such that it fits nicely in the gap in the bottom right corner. Hope someone can help!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes understood! will do, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % in real document remove option "demo"
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[textfont=bf]{caption}  % <--- new
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{siunitx}               % <--- new

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Linear regression/LinearReg_Fib}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Linear regression/LinearReg_RBC"}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Figures/Linear regression/LinearReg_Leuko"}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.459\linewidth}
    \centering
    \sisetup{group-four-digits}
\begin{tabular}{l S[table-format=4.1]S[table-format=-3.2] }
    \toprule
        & C10       & C01       \\
    \midrule
F/P low & 240.1     & 171.3     \\
F/P     & 763.5     & 269.08    \\
F/P mo  & 1201.0    & 190.6     \\
F/P h   & 6651.6    & -345.9    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Linear regression model between sample stiffness (determined as the tangent modulus at 75\%) and (a) Fibrin/platelet content, (b) Red blood cells and (c) Leukocytes}
\label{fig:LinearRegression}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
In table I suggest to use `S` columns defined in the  `siunitx` package. Using the, numbers in table are aligned at decimal points.

Comment: YES! Great, thanks so much for helping out!